# How to perform save in ASP.Net using angularjs

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I'm trying to save data to DB. The breakpoint is not hit in code behind and the data is not saved. All I see in the console log is - `PASS : [object Object]`. Where am i going wrong.

**default.aspx:**

```
<div data-ng-controller="defaultCtrl">
        Username
        <input type="text" id="txtUsername" data-ng-model="AdminUser.Username" />
        <br />
        Password
        <input type="text" id="txtPassword" data-ng-model="AdminUser.Password" />        
        <br />
        <button type="submit" data-ng-click="AddUser(AdminUser)">Submit</button>
</div>
```

**default.aspx.cs:**
**class:**

```
public class AdminUser
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }        
    }

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public void AddUser(AdminUser adminUser)
        { --breakpoint set here but not hit

            --code to save data
            AdminUserDB.AddUser(adminUser);
        }
```

**defaultCtrl.js:**

```
app.controller("defaultCtrl",["$scope","DefaultFactory",function ($scope,DefaultFactory){
$scope.AddUser = function (AdminUser) {
var promise = DefaultFactory.AddUser(AdminUser);
        promise.then(function (success) {
            console.log("PASS : " + success);
},
        function (error) {
            console.log("ERR : " + error);
        })
    }
}]);
```

**defaultFactory.js:**

```
app.factory("DefaultFactory", ["$http", function ($http) {
    var Factory = {};
    //add new user
    Factory.AddUser = function ($params) {   
        //console.log($params); -- i can see the object with the data in console.     
        return $http({
            url: "http://localhost:49271/default.aspx/AddUser",
            method: "GET", --when i put POST here, there is an error in console
            data: $params            
        })
            .success(function (data, status) {
        })
            .error(function (data, status) {
                console.log("DATA : " + data);
                console.log("STATUS : " + status);
        });
    };    
    return Factory;
}]);
```

Comment: For a start `<button type="submit" data-ng-click="AddUser(AdminUser)">Submit</button>` you don;t need to pass in `AdminUser` because it is attached to your scope, so you just use that in the function.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using WebApi?

Comment: @CallumLinington. Yes. Dont know that and I find this way more easy & convinient.

Comment: Trust me when I say this, in the long run you will find WebApi far more easier to use and far more flexible. It's worth learning. It won't take much, head over to [asp.net](http://www.asp.net) it is well worth it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use WebApi, you could shift your record-saving code into a second .aspx file (or a .ashx handler file, which just contains some C# code, but no HTML page) and do the saving from there.

```
return $http({
            url: "http://localhost:49271/SaveRecord.ashx",
            method: "POST", 
            data: $params            
        })
```

If you are posting JSON data to your .ashx file, you can use JSON.Net to deserialize your data back into a C# record...

```
public class SaveRecordHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //  Read in a JSON record which has been POSTED to a webpage, 
        //  and turn it back into an object.  
        string jsonString = "";
        HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        using (StreamReader inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
        {
            jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
        }

        YourDataClass oneQuestion = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourDataClass>(jsonString);
```

Hope this helps.